# intent.putExtra for the camera app

Tags: flash, android-intent, camera

As part of a school project, we are building an app that uses the camera. As part of an early design decision, we are using the camera Intent to access the camera. Later on, we wanted to control the camera better, like turn flash off.

In researching this, I came across a bunch of intent.putExtra parameters. Unfortunately I found only one parameter that the default android camera app accepts: MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT. At least the only documented parameter. I found a few others, but like crop, it seems not every device supports them. However, not even those have anything to control the flash.

Has anyone found a camera intent.putExtra parameter that controls flash? Even an unofficial undocumented one?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to send an intent to the camera, since what you are doing this way, is to open the camera App. 
What you need instead is to make an activity which uses the hardware camera, so you can use all the features. 
If you dont know how, let me know and i will tell you.

UPDATE:

i Think it is too much code to post here. 
If you want to research for yourself, you should start thinking about this:

- permission android.permission.CAMERA;
- Camera object. You can get an instance using Camera.open();
- SurfaceView. Will be the main layout of your activity, and here you will print what camera is capturing.
- Camera callbacks, and SurfaceView Callbacks.

This is a complex development, probably you will spend an evening dealing with it. 
Meanwhile, i will try to write a post in my blog with all the code, but you will learn more if you try to do it by yourself instead of a copy paste. Let me know if you have any doubt

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of the camera API. Unfortunately the team decided to do the intent as a get-it-ready-as-possible measure. And right now, it's too late to create a camera app or build one into our current app. As you said, it's a lot of code.